# mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener never called on Nexus Mobile

Tags: android

i'm using Custom video Recorder but i have a problem that the recorder is never stooped on Nexus,

here is what i do inside the recorder :

```
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(15000); // 15 seconds
    mediaRecorder.setOnInfoListener(this);

public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
        Log.d("hereee1", "msg");
        if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
             Log.v("VIDEOCAPTURE","Maximum Duration Reached"); 

             mr.stop();

          }
```